# Create Temporary Table Populated with Dates and LEFT JOIN to `created_at` Column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Original Query:

```
// Doesn't return dates with zero value

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( created_at ) AS DATE, COUNT( tweet_id ) AS count
FROM  `tweets` 
WHERE DATE( created_at ) >  '2012-11-01'
AND DATE( created_at ) <= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
GROUP BY DATE
```

Modified Query:

```
// Attempting to return all dates with a value of zero if doesn't exist in `created_at` column

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DateSummary1 ( date timestamp ) SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(created_at)) as date FROM tweets;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DateSummary2 ( date timestamp, number int ) SELECT DATE(created_at) as date, count(*) AS number FROM tweets WHERE DATE(created_at) > '2012-11-01' AND DATE(created_at) <= DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY created_at ASC;
SELECT ds1.date,ds2.number FROM DateSummary1 ds1 LEFT JOIN DateSummary2 ds2 on ds1.date=ds2.date;
```

Unfortunately, the latter result isn't providing me the dates with zero values like I had expected. What am I overlooking? I'm sure this is a logic error, but I'm not sure where my logic has faulted. I've gotten this far from reading copious threads on SO, Google, etc. but am not sure how to get over this final hurdle.

An example of the returned timestamps using jcho360's suggestion:

```
1387286811
1387286812
1387286813
1387286815
1387286820
```

Comment: I am not really clear on what you are trying to do.  What do you mean by dates with a "value of zero" as mentioned in the comments? Why are you dealing with Unix timestamps? Why are you working with temp tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( created_at ) AS DATE, COUNT( tweet_id ) AS count
FROM  `tweets` 
WHERE (DATE( created_at ) >  '2012-11-01'
AND DATE( created_at ) <= DATE( NOW( ) ) )
or DATE( created_at ) = date ('000-00-00') //I added this Line
GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still just returns the data set without adding in the  missing dates, and the respective value of '0'. Thanks for the thought tho.

Comment: For whatever reason, it is still skipping the non-existent times in the result set. I converted the timestamps back to standard time format, and it's accounting for each second as I'm not doing a DATE_FORMAT on it currently. Yet, it skips seconds that have no count value. I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: I added an example of the timestamps being returned from this query to the question for clarity.

Comment: @DroBuddy could you put the structure and some data in sqlfiddle.com to help you with the best solution